# R - round to nearest half

Tags: r, rounding, numeric

I have the following data:

```
> vec
 [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.4 1.9 2.4 3.1 3.6 4.1 4.6 5.0 5.5 6.0 6.5 7.0 7.4 7.9 8.4 9.1
```

which I need to round to the nearest .5.

Let me be more specific: 1.4 becomes 1.5, and 1.9 becomes 2.0. Also, 2.4 becomes 2.5, and 3.1 becomes 3.0. And so on. The vector I expect is:

```
> vec
 [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5 6.0 6.5 7.0 7.5 8.0 8.5 9.0
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: `round(vec/0.5)*0.5` - this is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail for pointing out a previous topic.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know what language you're using,  but the math would be
NUM = INTEGER (NUM x 2) / 2

Comment: It says on the title: it is R. But never mind, this question had been asked already.